# "Triangular" layout in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, lattice

With the following snippet:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, every arrow/.append style = {dash}]
    &  H_5 = S_3 & \\
    H_1 \arrow[ur] & H_2 \arrow[u] & H_3 \arrow[ul] & H_4 \arrow[ull] \\
    & \arrow[ul] \arrow[u] \arrow[ur] \arrow[urr] H_0 &
\end{tikzcd}
```

I get:

[image]

I'd like the top and bottom entries (i.e. $H_0$ and $H_5 = S_3$) to be positioned so that they are equidistant to $H_2$ and $H_3$ below them, rather than being shifted over to the left. I thought that using one fewer column in the top and bottom row would do the trick, but evidently not.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe adding more columns and put H5=S3 between H2 and H3?

Comment: I changed 2.5em to 3em, which seems slightly better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a column, but make some space between columns smaller to cover your tracks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, arrows=dash]
  &&[-3em]  H_5 = S_3 &[-3em] \\
  H_1 \arrow[urr] & H_2 \arrow[ur] &&  H_3 \arrow[ul] & H_4 \arrow[ull] \\
  && H_0 \arrow[ull] \arrow[ul] \arrow[ur] \arrow[urr]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the simpler way to get all arrows to be dashes.

Comment: Do you have a reference, why ur and Co. are allowed as optional arguments in \arrow[ur]? I was not able to locate the specific case of direction options in the manual (https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), only the general \arrow[options]{<arrow end tip>}. In particular, I am interested whether the degree of the edge is dependent on the target node position.

Comment: @user7427029 The manual of `tikz-cd` https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-cd/0

Comment: Ouch. Thanks!!!